# Storing results in a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to compute arithmetic calculations and store the results in a new list in Prolog.
The function prototype goes as follows:

```
calculation(List1, ListofLists, ResultList)
```

for the first argument I provide a list, for the second argument a list of lists and third the result list. I compute the first argument list with each list of list of lists and store the result in the resulting list.
So can somebody tell me how can I store results in the resulting (empty) list?

Comment: Is there anything you attempted yourself? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 2):

With [library lambda](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord) you can write:

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

calculation(L1, L2, Compute, L) :-
    maplist([L2,Compute] +\X^Y^call(Compute,L2, X, Y), L1, L).

% my_compute succeeds when R is the list of all the products
% of the numbers component of L with the number V
my_compute(L, V, R) :-
    maplist(V +\X^Y^maplist(V +\Z^T^(T #= Z * V), X, Y), L, R).
```

Here is an example:

```
?- calculation([1,2,3], [[4,5],[6,7]], my_compute, Zss).
Zss = [[[4, 5], [6, 7]], [[8, 10], [12, 14]], [[12, 15], [18, 21]]].

?- Zss = [[[4,5],[6,7]],[[8,10],[12,14]],[[12,15],[18,21]]],
   calculation(Xs, [[4,5],[6,7]], my_compute, Zss).
Xs = [1, 2, 3].

?- Zss = [[[4,5],[6,7]],[[8,10],[12,14]],[[12,15],[18,21]]],
   calculation([1,2,3], Xss, my_compute, Zss).
Xss = [[4, 5], [6, 7]].
```

Comment: @repeat: in SWI, to avoid library path issues, better to install using `?- pack_install(lambda).`

Comment: @CapelliC.  Is that particular version really up-to-date?

Answer (score 1):

```
calculation([], [], []).
calculation([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [Z|Zs]) :-
    calculate(X, Y, Z),
    calculation(Xs, Ys, Zs).
```

which is identical to:

```
calculation(X, Y, Z) :-
    maplist(calculate, X, Y, Z).
```

either way, you need a predicate `calculate/3` that takes a first argument, a list of lists as the second argument, and calculates a result. For example, summing the list in the second argument and multiplying it to the first argument:

```
calculate(X, Ys, Z) :-
    list_sum(Ys, S),
    Z is X * S.
```

Comment: distraction free, and really instructive!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to do some computation on `List1` and every member of `ListofLists`, and get a list of results.

You can do this using findall:

```
calculation(List1, ListofLists, ResultList) :-
    findall(Result, (
        member(List2, ListofLists),
        your_computation(List1, List2, Result)
    ), ResultList).
```

For example, if you replace `your_compuation` with `append`, you get:

```
?- calculation([a,b],[[c,d],[e,f,g],[h]],X).
X = [[a, b, c, d], [a, b, e, f, g], [a, b, h]].
```